# Calculating distances between buildings, plots and road network using geometry expression

Tags: qgis, geometry, distance, expression

I am trying to measure the distance between the edge of a building edge to the closest road within the buildings plot to see whether there is enough space for a Electric vehicle parking space.
I have started using the expression that was given in this previous answer:[Calculating distances between buildings, plots and road network](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383533/calculating-distances-between-buildings-plots-and-road-network)

However, I am having issues when creating actual geometries. When I am putting in the copied and pasted expression I am getting an error stating that the expression is invalid  "Eval Error: Layer 'street' could not be loaded.". I have renamed and resaved my layers. Do you know why this could be? [image]

Comment: Open the dropdown "map layers" to the right, scroll to your streets layer and double click it so insert the correct name into your expression.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please add your code as **text** not a picture

Comment: There is a space at the end of your layer name `street ` (and another one in the geopackage name). Also look at the `plots` geopacakge/layer.  If you don't want to rename, use `"street "`, with double quotes around the layer name